# Is System.ConsoleKeyInfo.Key a virtual key code?

Tags: .net, windows-console

I am implementing my own version of [PSHostRawUserInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.pshostrawuserinterface%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'd like to implement [PSHostRawUserInterface.ReadKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.prompt%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and therefore I need to map [System.Management.Automation.Host.KeyInfo.VirtualKeyCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.keyinfo.virtualkeycode%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to [System.ConsoleKeyInfo.Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.key.aspx).

I can cast System.ConsoleKeyInfo.Key to an int, I just don't know if that's actually the VirtualKeyCode.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* I tested this some time back and the answer was "yes, but." See below for cautions. You can test that answer by writing a program that outputs the integer values of all the [ConsoleKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekey.aspx) values and compares them to the [Virtual Key Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Note, though, that `ConsoleKeyInfo.Key` is just the key, without the modifiers. A Virtual Key Code is a bitmapped value that includes modifiers (Shift, Control, Alt). With `ConsoleKeyInfo`, the modifiers are stored in the `Modifiers` property.

Alternately, you could compare the values of the `ConsoleKey` enumeration to the values of the [Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) enumeration, which specifically says that the values correspond to virtual key codes.

Comment: Jim, didn't test this yet, but I also found a utility to get keyboard scan codes: http://www.winterdrache.de/freeware/utilities.html

Answer (score 0):

I compared [ConsoleKey enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekey?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN) (System), [Keys enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=windowsdesktop-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN) (System.Windows.Forms) and [Virtaul Key Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes?redirectedfrom=MSDN). If we leave only the differences, we get this:

[image]